# WPF User Controls with Storyboard Animations are Jerky / Choppy

Tags: wpf, performance, animation

I am adding multiple usercontrols to a Canvas.  Each control has its own storyboard which executes on load.  I'm noticing that it is very choppy and jerky as its executing the 20 second animation.  It is not incredibly complex and I would have expected better performance.  Any gotchas I should be looking out for?  Here is a sample of the storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="mystoryboard" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(BlurEffect.Radius)" Storyboard.TargetName="itemgroup">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="30"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="30"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="itemgroup">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0.96"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="1"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:7" Value="1"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8" Value="1"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="itemgroup">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.1"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="itemgroup">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.1"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="itemgroup">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-60"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Comment: watch your system resources to see if its pegging out the CPU.  Also, update your vidya drivers.

Comment: It is definitely increasing the CPU, but is it b/c of something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: hard to tell.  Might have something to do with the behavior of splines.  You should try a very simplified version of this in a test project and see if a single control being animated exhibits the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a similar situation with a relatively simple storyboard animation of Shapes on a Canvas.  For me, a DropShadowEffect was the culprit; removing the drop shadow smoothed out the animations.  Do you have any effects applied to your usercontrols?

Comment: It is really help full, I removed the shadow it is works smooth, but for some reason i need shadow how can I do with that? @GregM

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to make an animation run smoothly with a DropShadowEffect applied.  I worked around it by removing the effect before the animation and adding it back after it ends... not ideal.